# Difference between CML and ECL

Tags: transistors, bjt

How is Emitter Coupled Logic different from Current Mode Logic. I have seen written in "*Microelectronics Circuits*" by **Sedra Smith** that CML is based on ECL . If it is so can anybody explain how they are related?

Comment: They are effectively the same in a broad sense, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic). Maybe a particular author makes a distinction in his book, but that's not general knowledge.

Comment: You could say that ECL is a possible implementation of CML. One could make an ECL-based circuit but with MOSFETs instead of BJTs. Then you wouldn't call it ECL as there are no emitters ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THis is an ECL circuit. Notice the output is from the emitters of two BJTs:

[image]

(source: [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ECL.svg))

This is a CML circuit:

[image]

(source: [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CML_output_stage.svg))

Notice the outputs are from the collectors of two BJTs.

> explain how they are related?

The CML output is essentially the ECL output with the emitter followers taken away.

What does this mean in applications?:

- ECL outputs require pull-down resistors to bias the output buffers correctly. CML does not.
- ECL outputs can be combined in wired-OR configuration; CML outputs can not.
- CML outputs are 50-ohm matched. ECL outputs are low-impedance and require series termination if they need to be matched (which reduce signal swing). Typically ECL is run with matched termination at the load only.
- CML's common mode level tends to be very near VCC. ECL's is about 1 V below VCC.

Comment: And one more thing please, what is so special about CML/ECL logic family than others?

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi, you could ask that as a new question. It probably would help to specify what other logic families you want to compare with.